# Get Name tag from XML

Tags: sql, xpath

```
<Attribute DisplayOrder="-1">
    <Categories>
<Category Name="Properties">
<Properties>
<Property Name="Visible" Value="True"/>
<Property Name="Enabled" Value="False"/>
<Property Name="Mandatory" Value="True"/>
<Property Name="Button" Value="True"/>
<Property Name="Label">
                    <Locales>
                        <Locale Name="en" Value="Device Selection Button"/>
                    </Locales>
                </Property>
<Property Name="Style" Value=""/>
<Property Name="ShowHelpText" Value="False"/>
<Property Name="EventChange" Value="False"/>
<Property Name="Mask" Value=""/>
<Property Name="NumberOfLines" Value="1"/>
<Property Name="EditType" Value="0"/>
<Property Name="ButtonCaption">
                    <Locales>
                        <Locale Name="en" Value="Select Device"/>
                    </Locales>
                </Property>
</Properties>
</Category>
<Category Name="External Functions">
<Properties>
<Property Name="function" Value="SelectEquipmentByCategory"/>
<Property Name="actionType" Value="SetOne"/>
<Property Name="Parameters" Value="Devices_Cat,4355608"/>
</Properties>
</Category>
</Categories>
</Attribute>
```

I have this XML and in SQL i want the value of  as Select Device.

Query :

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(display_info_xml), '/Attribute/Categories/Properties/Property[@Name="Label"]/Locales/Locale[@Name="en"]/Value') 
FROM table
```

Now the Query is returning blank.
I tried to create all XPATHs but no use.
Please Help.

EDIT :

updated Query :

/Attribute/Categories/Category[@Name="Properties"]/Properties/Property[@Name="Label"]/Locales/Locale[@Name="en"]/Value

Still failing with no data in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try it like this

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(display_info_xml), '//Property[@Name="ButtonCaption"]/Locales/Locale[@Name="en"]/Value') 
FROM table
```

OR

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(display_info_xml), '/Attribute/Categories/Category/Properties/Property[@Name="ButtonCaption"]/Locales/Locale[@Name="en"]/Value') 
FROM table
```

you write you want the value of as Select Device in your example you point the value of as Device Selection button

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Category` tag.

Also, the `Value` attribute should be prepended with `@`. (http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathattribute.php)

The correct XPATH is `/Attribute/Categories/Category/Properties/Property[@Name="Label"]/Locales/Locale[@Name="en"]/@Value`.